# Bootstrap - feedback

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've heard today of a new framework produced by Twitter.

Link to the framework: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

I'm wondering if someone has used it already and what they think about it.

And what kind of website can use this framework?

I'm currently developing a web app in PHP/MSYQL/jQuery/jQuery UI can i use it in the same time?

And the last question, what kind of technologies do they use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from being the [most watched repository](https://github.com/popular/watched) over at GitHub, Twitter's Boostrap allows you to create carefully crafted sites with intuitive UI's and with usability in mind. It has a good backwards compatibility track record, so you can support older browsers like IE7, so you don't have to worry about breaking your design with complex layouts (as long as you stick to the grid) in aging browsers.

Healthy code, carefully crafted grid system, responsive design, ample UI elements and bountiful jQuery custom plugins are just a few things that separate the bootstrap from the rest and there is still a lot of room for growth.

And yes, it can be used along with the jQuery UI framework, jQuery is at the heart of the framework.

Comment: Love your answer it's exactly what i'm looking for and i didn't know that it was based on jQuery as well.

Comment: Well, i think concurrent to jquery ui in fact... if i understand it correctly.

Comment: @Jerome jQuery UI elements are all prefixed so none of them interfere with the bootstrap elements or UI elements so they can both coincide together nicely. Though there have been efforts started to "mix" the UI of the two into one one solution, like this project for example: [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used it and I really like it, it's great for use when you're worried about cross-browser compability. Here's my site, if you're interested:

http://rest-link.com/dc/

Any type of website can use it. I implemented all of the AJAX found on this site, it pretty much only comes with the HTML and CSS. I love the look of the buttons and the forms. Being a programmer, I'm not always great at designing things. I like to think it's an easy and quick to launch an "idea" website.